# I can't click to pick up & place items in inventory on Windows 8 Minecraft. Can this be enabled?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, mouse, windows-8

I have a laptop that has Windows 8 which I use for playing Minecraft. However when using the inventory, I have to hold my mouse to drag and pick the items and I don't like that.

I have tried switching mouses but that didn't work, is this possible to fix?

Answer (score 8):

Go into <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Controls</kbd> and turn <kbd>Touchscreen Mode</kbd> to OFF.

Answer (score 0):

you should just be able to left click and then move the mouse then left click again. (the fact you are on windows 8 doesnt change anything, it is the version of minecraft and set up of your mouse that could change this)

Comment: It actually does. Windows 8 laptops with touchscreens automatically enable the features to handle touch-input, which Minecraft picks up and recognises, and enables it's own settings which alter mouse behaviour. This behaviour can be disabled as per [colorfusion's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/214476/28182)